# Suggestions for displaying a UL below a form input for ajax-autosuggestions

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm looking for some CSS/HTML input on how to position UL LI elements below a form text input field. The LI's would be created/removed dynamically with javascript after an ajax call.

```
    <div>
                     <label for="edit-query">Search: </label>
                     <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="query" id="edit-query" size="60" value="" class="form-text" />
 <ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Essentially I would like the items to appear above the rest of the page content, and directly below the form input. (probably need to use a z-index property).

Comment: if you want to use libraries, jquery-ui has a very useful autocomplete widget

Comment: I'm essentially just looking for something to help me display the data I'm returning from my server, as far as getting the data is concerned I've got that covered. I'm not a huge fan of messing with HTML/CSS layouts/positioning :/ Kinda boring.

Comment: Well unfortunately unless you are using a plugin like jQuery UI to do it, messing with HTML/CSS is exaclty what you will have to do. You can have a div positioned absolutely below the textbox and have the UL inside that. Clear it each time your AJAX returns and add the new items returned.

Comment: Take a look at this little example. Firstly, I'd like to state that this is fairly crude and unpolished, secondly I'm not retrieving my data from AJAX and thirdly it uses a table instead of a UL however all these differences are trivial and will be easy to convert

http://jsfiddle.net/B5WtQ/2/

Comment: What ' rest of the page content'? I don't see any... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for displaying a UL below a form input for ajax-autosuggestions

```js
const suggestionEl = document.getElementById("suggestions");

function onChangeInput(e) {
  const inputVal  = e.target.value
  const suggestionValues = getSuggestions(inputVal);
  suggestionEl.innerHTML = suggestionValues;
}

function getSuggestions(value) {
  const suggestionCount =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  let suggestionValues = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < suggestionCount; i++) {
    suggestionValues += `<li onclick="selectOption(event)">${value}-${i}</li>`
  }
  return suggestionValues;
}

function selectOption(e) {
  const inputVal  = e.target.innerHTML;
  suggestionEl.innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("autosuggestion").value = inputVal
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
}

#container input{
  width: 300px;
}

#suggestions {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#suggestions li {
      display: block;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h3>Autosuggestion with HTML/CSS/JS</h3>

<div id="container">
  <input type="text" onkeyup="onChangeInput(event)" id="autosuggestion" />
  <ul id="suggestions">
    
  </ul>
</div>
```